# htaccess redirect rule on CENT OS server

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have a new server setup on CENT OS machine.
I am facing problem with htaccess redirect.
Framework - Silverstripe Php frmawork. (due to htaccess redirect issue framework is not working.)
 in php_info() I can see - 
 Loaded Modules - mod_rewrite

Following is one of the sample redirect code I am using on my project. Redirect from root/go dir. to root/trk/link.php. It is working fine on old linux server but not on this new server, Here I am getting "Not found" error.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
Redirect /go/ /trk/link.php?param=
</IfModule>
```

is there any specific setting I need to do in apache (httpd.conf) file???

Comment: As always in such cases: look at the log file, that is what it is there for. And probably turning on redirect logging is a good idea too, don't you think? After you did that, come here and ask with more specific details.

Comment: <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
Redirect /go/ /trk/link.php?param=
</IfModule>
Here is the full sample htaccess code.

Comment: Also, if you are running this server yourself, so you have full administrative power over that http daemon, why do you use `.htaccess` style rewriting? Try to define static rewriting rules in the main configuration of the http daemon. `.htaccess` files are slowing down everything, they are harder to debug and often unnecessary.

Comment: @arkascha - thank you. Can you help me with find exact error from log files. I can see there are two recent log files are updated.
messages and
secure
I dont find any specific error log record is generated in there.

Comment: @arkascha - What if in case I have php framework installed in there and framework is using htaccess redirect rules.

Comment: I was referring to the http daemons log files, not the system log files. Their location depends on your setup, in CentOS it is probably the old fashioned `/var/log/httpd/`. There should be at least an access and an error log file in there. And a redirect log file, if you turned that on in the daemons configuration.

Comment: If your framework insists on using `.htaccess` style files you either have to accept that and play that game, or you have it generate the rewriting rules once and transfer them to the main configuration afterwards. Stick with the first option for now.

Comment: Okay I found the exact log file that you are talking about, I can see these error in there but still it didn't make any seance to me, because I am not that much good with server setups and log files :P

- - domainname myipadd - - [19/Nov/2013:00:36:23 -0700] "GET /go/appcode/1/ HTTP/1.1" 404 211

[Tue Nov 19 00:36:23 2013] [error] [client myipadd] File does not exist: /apache/root/go/appcode

Comment: OK, that is the request resulting in a 404 error since obviously the rewriting does not catch at all. You need to activate logging inside the rewriting module. Since you are aparently using the apache http daemon you should refer to the excellent documentation of the rewriting module: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: Oh, another hint: you might have to enable support for `.htaccess` style files first. You do that in the main http server configuration. It is typically switched off, since it is a security thread.

Comment: Can you please specify where do i exactly find the main http server configuration file ???

Comment: You are running a public http server but have never touched its configuration? Oh my... Have a look at /etc/httpd or similar _and read the documentation_! You cannot operate a server on the internet without considering at least the most basic configuration details. We are talking about basic security of _your_ system here!

Comment: :).......... I am in /etc/httpd/conf... and in there is a apache settings file - httpd.conf...... I am checking it... lets see if I understood anything in here :P............

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the `IfModule` container and the rewrite engine line. The `Redirect` directive is part of mod_alias, which is usually always loaded. You don't need to check for mod_rewrite at all. So you just need:

```
Redirect /go/ /trk/link.php?param=
```

Note that this *redirects the browser*, but considering that you had this on another server, I'm sure you know that that's happening.